# loops,dont understand

Tags: python, loops, break, continue

I am begginer in python and I dont understand,have to meake a loop for this comands,I wont to they work in loop,forexample - when I told "write file" code works, and do the next step of code , "read file" and then exit. But now work only one part of code!
Thank You a lot for yor time!

```
import pyttsx3
engine = pyttsx3.init()
import speech_recognition as sr
import datetime
import webbrowser
import speech_recognition as sr
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image
from pytesseract import image_to_string
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:\\Program Files\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe'




def say(talk):
    engine.say(talk)
    engine.runAndWait()

say("Hello, Let's Start!")


record = sr.Recognizer()
try:

    with sr.Microphone(device_index=1) as source:
        print("Speak Now Please!........")
        audio = record.listen(source)
        result = record.recognize_google(audio)
        result = result.lower()
        print(result)


        if result == "write file":
            str_file = image_to_string(Image.open('Images/photo.png'))
            file = open("text_from.txt", "w")
            file.write(str_file)
            file.close()



        elif result == "read file":
            file = open("text_from.txt", "rt")
            for line in file:
                print(line)
            file.close()

        elif result == "exit":
            print("exit")
            



except sr.UnknownValueError:
    print("Talk again")

except sr.RequestError:
    print("Somthing going wrong")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know how correct it is, but i find the way.maybe thats helps someone.

```
`import pyttsx3
engine = pyttsx3.init()
import speech_recognition as sr
import datetime
import webbrowser
import speech_recognition as sr
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image
from pytesseract import image_to_string
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:\\Program Files\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe'




def say(talk):
    engine.say(talk)
    engine.runAndWait()

say("Hello, Let's Start!")

result = False
record = sr.Recognizer()
try:
    with sr.Microphone(device_index=1) as source:
        print("SPEAK NOW ...................")
        audio = record.listen(source)
        result = record.recognize_google(audio)
        result = result.lower()
        print(result)


        while result == "write file":
            str_file = image_to_string(Image.open('Images/photo.png'))
            file = open("text_from.txt", "w")
            file.write(str_file)
            file.close()

            with sr.Microphone(device_index=1) as source:
                print("SPEAK NOW ...................")
                audio = record.listen(source)
                result = record.recognize_google(audio)
                result = result.lower()
                print(result)



        while result == "read file":
             file = open("text_from.txt", "rt")
             for line in file:
                 print(line)
             file.close()

             with sr.Microphone(device_index=1) as source:
                 print("SPEAK NOW ...................")
                 audio = record.listen(source)
                 result = record.recognize_google(audio)
                 result = result.lower()
                 print(result)


        while result == "exit":
            print("")
            break





except sr.UnknownValueError:
    print("Talk again")

except sr.RequestError:
    print("Somthing going wrong")
`
```